# How to draw a figure using loops and system.out.print/println

Tags: java

Task: Given an integer "n".If n = 1 print out:

```
/|
 |
```

if n = 2 print out:

```
 /|
/ |
  |
  |
```

and so on... How can i solve this task?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1;i++){
        if(n == 1){
            System.out.print(" /");
            System.out.print("|\n");
            System.out.println("  |");
        }else if(n == 2){
            System.out.println(" /");
            System.out.print("/");
            System.out.print(" |\n");
            System.out.print("  |\n");
            System.out.print("  |\n");
            System.out.print("  |\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the use of your loop ?

Comment: try to decompose the problem in simpler parts: you generally have to print _2n_ lines, where each of the first _n_ (use a `for`) contains _n_ characters followed by a `|`, all these characters (use an inner `for`) are spaces, except one which is a `/` (use an `if` to check the index), and so on...

Comment: _How?_ Find a pattern that you could use to build this half arrow using a loop. This is a good exercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge here is in writing code for the loops to handle the formatting on each line.  In general, we want to print some number of spaces, followed by a forward slash, followed by more spaces, ending the line with a vertical pipe.

```
for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j=i; j < n-1; ++j) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print("/");
    for (int j=i; j > 0; --j) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("|");
}

for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j < n; ++j) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("|");
}
```

**Output for n=1**

```
/|
 |
```

**Output for n=2**

```
 /|
/ |
  |
  |
```

**Output for n=3**

```
  /|
 / |
/  |
   |
   |
   |
```

Comment: `It's not working` is just about the least helpful thing you could possibly comment.  I have given you code which meets the requirements you showed us.  If there be additional requirements, then reveal them.

Comment: Sorry for the first comment.Working,but my output does not same as your output.

Comment: Sorry had a typo in there.  The last line of the first outer `for` loop should be this: `System.out.println("|");`

Comment: Yeah,it's working fine now.Than you very much.You're very helpful!